# Why can't I install IE 11?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11

I have a windows 7 computer that refuses to install IE 11. I get a 40025 error code when I attempt to install it.

I narrowed it down to problems with DISM by using this article - [(Solved) IE11 Install Problem: Neutral package installation failed (exit code = 0x00003715 (14101)) and Setup exit code: 0x00009C59 (40025)](https://jingyangli.wordpress.com/2015/08/18/ie11-install-problem-neutral-package-installation-failed-exit-code-0x00003715-14101-and-setup-exit-code-0x00009c59-40025/).

When I go to run

```
C:\Windows\system32>dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\Temp\I
E12644.tmp\IE11-neutral.Extracted.cab /quiet /norestart
```

I get

```
Error: 2

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

However, I am 100% sure the file is there and the path is correct. I even Shift-Right clicked the file and used Copy as Path.

The strange thing was, one time I tried running the DISM command, I got a completely different error code.

```
Error: 14101

The identities of the manifests are identical but their contents are different.
```

Ideas?

Comment: What makes you think that running this command will install IE11 you are still more then likely going to get the same error.  The link does not work for me, so I can't verify, what you have or have not done correctly.

Comment: Are all other updates installed? Is the system clean of viruses and malware?

Comment: [System Update Readiness Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-is-the-system-update-readiness-tool) should help.

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes, every update is installed. The only update that shows up is the install for Internet Explorer 11. Yes it is clean.

Comment: @Ramhound I will try the Readiness Tool, and as to your first comment, I believe it will help install IE 11 since the article seems to be about the same issue. If anything this will narrow the problem down more. As far as the link not working, I'm not sure. I've tried it on multiple computers and it seems to work for me.

Comment: I know precisely the reason it isn't working, my point is that, your question is less verbose without you supplying the relevant information.  Having read similar articles before, there isn't that information, on how to solve a problem like this normally.

Comment: @Ramhound The log for the System Readiness Tool says `No errors detected`

Comment: Can you try downgrading to IE9 then using the standalone installed suggested by @WesSayeed?

Comment: @Burgi The machine actually has 9 already. 10 will not install, gives the same error code.

Comment: 40025 = USER_ERROR_NEUTRAL_CAB_INSTALL_FAILED . https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/setup-problems-with-ie11 look in the CBS.log why it fails